# numpy indexing into array of dtype=object

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, indexing

I am creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences, like this:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8,9], [10]], dtype=object)
```

In a next step, I want to use a "boolean mask" of the same length as `arr` to get certain elements.

Passing a mask of all `True` works:

```
my_mask = [True, True, True, True]
arr[my_mask]
# array([[list([1, 2]), list([3, 4, 5]), list([6, 7, 8, 9]), list([10])]],
      dtype=object)
```

However, other masks don't seem to work:

```
my_mask = [True, False, True, True]
arr[my_mask]
# array([], shape=(0, 4), dtype=object)
```

Why does the above result in an empty array?

**UPDATE:** In the example above I wrote `arr[my_mask]`, but the error I got locally was actually obtained via `arr[True, False, True, True]`, which should rather be `arr[[True, False, True, True]]`, note the double brackets. Thanks to @Ivan and @user1740577. As such, this is not unexpected behavior, but rather a user mistake during indexing.

Comment: this work for me and output is : `array([list([1, 2]), list([6, 7, 8, 9]), list([10])], dtype=object)
`

Comment: which version of numpy are you using ? I got the same output as @user1740577

Comment: I am using numpy 1.21.2

Comment: @S.A. are you actually calling `arr[my_mask]` or doing `arr[True, True, True, True]` directly?

Comment: @Ivan - I was doing `arr[True, False, True, True]` and I am just seeing that `arr[my_mask]` actually works! How weird, do you know why? Thanks already!

Comment: about using bool to index array, i found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58132572/10666066

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using:

```
arr[True, False, True, True]
```

using this (when you want to pass `mask`, pass `array of mask`):

```
arr[[True, False, True, True]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call `arr[my_mask]` instead of `arr[True, False, True, True]`.

The reason is that by indexing with `True` you are adding a dimension,

```
>>> arr[True]
array([[list([1, 2]), list([3, 4, 5]), list([6, 7, 8, 9]), list([10])]],
      dtype=object)
```

but then mask the second axis (formerly the first axis) with `False` *i.e.* returning no elements.